# Scratch Pad software for Windows

Tags: math-software

I'm looking for software that can serve as a replacement for a physical "scratch pad", on a Windows system with only keyboard and touchpad interfaces.  This is intended to facilitate manual calculations, but not actually do any computation.

$\LaTeX$ is good for some things, but I haven't found an easy way to do things like vertical addition/subtraction/multiplication/division with the same speed & comfort as I might do on a scratch pad.

Excel and Notepad can serve the purpose, but they're a bit clumsy at it.  Paint could do, but is not so great to use without a mouse.

Is there any purpose-built "scratch pad" software out there?  Or, are there other workarounds I might not have thought of which work well on a laptop with no regular mouse?

Comment: I think you are in the wrong SE board. Your question is not a mathematical one.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I posted the question in chat, and was told there are already similar questions for other mathematical software requests here - so, presumably, this would be acceptable.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: [Help Center > Asking](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that questions about "software that mathematicians use" are on-topic. This appears to fall in that category.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Math has math handwriting recognition capabilities.

[MS Math](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15702)

A few other products claim similar functionality:

[MoboMath](http://www.enventra.com/products/mobomath/overview.htm)

[FluidMath](http://www.fluiditysoftware.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=7)

Comment: My problem with these, as with Paint, is that "handwriting" with a touchpad isn't exactly fun.

Comment: Ah, you said touch*pad*. I was thinking touch*screen*.

Comment: I'm searching for the same sort of thing - MS Math doesn't work, because it stubbornly refuses to simply let me write down what I need... It solves everything, which I don't want out of a scratch pad. Has anyone found any software that allows you to write mathematical equations nicely, in order to solve them manually?

Answer (score 2):

You might try [**Math-o-mir**](http://gorupec.awardspace.com/mathomir.html). I haven't used it myself but the site says:

> The idea behind Math-o-mir was: "why can't I use my PC as simple as I am using pencil when writing mathematical equations?"